# mysql lock error or bug?

Tags: mysql, locking

here we go:

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES radcheck WRITE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM radcheck WHERE id NOT IN (
    ->     SELECT id FROM (
    ->         SELECT id FROM radcheck  WHERE attribute = 'Password' GROUP BY UserName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ->      ) AS c
    -> );
ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'radcheck' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

WTF?

EDIT

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOCK TABLES radcheck WRITE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM radcheck WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM radcheck  WHERE attribute = 'Password' GROUP BY UserName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 );
ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'radcheck' was not locked with LOCK TABLES



mysql> LOCK TABLES radcheck READ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM radcheck WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM radcheck  WHERE attribute = 'Password' GROUP BY UserName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 );
ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'radcheck' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

pd: The query works fine if I not lock the table.
pd: This is only an examply ti simplify the question.. in real life is an DELETE...

Comment: check my answer. you need to give alias to all tables. and need to lock subquery table too with that alias

Answer (score 12, accepted):

when you use lock tables, you need to lock all tables in your query.
When you use a subquery it creates a table. and you are not locking it.
because of that you are getting error.

reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

give an alias to inner table

tested sample:

```
lock tables products as p1 write, products as p2 write ;
select product_id  from products as p1
where product_id  not in ( 
select product_id from products p2 where product_id in (1,2)
)
```

And probably you need to this:

```
lock tables radcheck as r1 write, radcheck as r2 write ;

 SELECT * FROM radcheck r1 WHERE id NOT IN (
SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT id FROM radcheck r2 WHERE attribute = 'Password' GROUP BY UserName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS c
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have autocommit = 1 and after commit release the tables.

try with:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
```

before to start your transaction.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/innodb-and-autocommit.html

Answer (score 0):

You are locking tables for `WRITE`. You need to lock tables for `READ` as you are using `SELECT` that just reads from the tables.

However you should not really be locking tables as this prevents concurrency.

**EDIT**

You also need to use aliases as you are using the same table twice in the query.

i.e.

```
LOCK TABLES radcheck AS read1 READ, radcheck AS read2 READ;
SELECT * 
FROM radcheck AS read1
WHERE id NOT IN
   (
       SELECT id FROM radcheck AS read2
       WHERE attribute = 'Password'
       GROUP BY UserName
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   );
```