# How do I LOCK TABLES for an UPDATE-JOIN query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This query sequence works:

```sql
LOCK TABLES order_product WRITE, product READ;
UPDATE order_product
    SET order_product.quantity = order_product.quantity + 1;
```

And this query (without LOCK TABLES) works too:

```sql
UPDATE order_product
    INNER JOIN product ON order_product.product_id = product.id
    SET order_product.quantity = order_product.quantity + 1;
```

But this query sequence fails with an error:

```sql
LOCK TABLES order_product WRITE, product READ;
UPDATE order_product
    INNER JOIN product ON order_product.product_id = product.id
    SET order_product.quantity = order_product.quantity + 1;
```

Error:

```
#1100 - Table 'order_product' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

**Why does this combination of LOCK TABLES, UPDATE, and INNER JOIN result in this error?**

At first, I believed that my issue was the one resolved in [a similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943155/4639640), but I cannot imagine what I would do differently with my query to use table aliases to resolve the problem.

The closest information I have found comes from [a answer on DBA stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34177), but the solution did not work for me, and the conversation went a bit over my head.

More importantly, how should I construct my query so that it doesn't fail? In my example, I have stripped down the query to be as understandable as possible at the expense of minimizing its usefulness, but I want the lock for atomicity and the join for a WHERE clause.

*Observed in MariaDB 10.1.36 with InnoDB tables.*

Comment: Have you tried to do the LOCK TABLES and UPDATE within a single transaction (or with SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;)? Also, you shouldn't need to explicitly lock any tables and you will still get row-level locking, which will provide better concurrency.

Comment: I don't see how wrapping it in a transaction would change anything, but maybe I'll try that. I do want table-level locking because I don't want new records to be inserted.

Comment: This is admittedly out of context: The correct way to use LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES with transactional tables, such as InnoDB tables, is to begin a transaction with SET autocommit = 0 (not START TRANSACTION) followed by LOCK TABLES, and to not call UNLOCK TABLES until you commit the transaction explicitly. See http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html

Comment: But I think it just means that if you **want** to wrap your locks and updates within a transaction, this is how to do it. On my version of MySql (5.6.27), wrapping the locks in a transaction is **not** necessary, so you have a different issue. Sorry I could not help.